# Assembly missing error after upload a developed website by MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I wrote a site by Asp.net mvc and publish it and now want to upload it , when i upload it , i encountered with this error :

**Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

(http://gol.datagts.net)

what can i do for this ? 
Is there any body out there to help me ?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at properties of your assembly (in reference folder) : set copyLocal : true